# Is 'NSIntersectsRect' from a non-public API? If so, are there alternatives?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, api, public

I'm using the above class for an app that I am trying to submit to the app store. It gives me the error "the app references non-public symbols in Payload/*app name*.app/*app name*: NSIntersectsRect". If this is non-public, does anyone know of a class that can serve the same function (that is, detect when a rectangle overlaps another), or am I going to have to figure out a custom workaround?

Comment: It is public according to apple docs, I didn't find any references to such a problem on the net either. Maybe it complains about some other method around your call to NSIntersectsRect? Also, you can either implement it yourself or try to wrap it up with NSIntersectionRect with checking returning rect.

Comment: The error message specifically points to NSIntersectsRect. Could you elaborate your suggestion of NSIntersectionRect in an answer?

Comment: `NSInteresctsRect` is public. This most likely means that either the rejection reason is wrong, or App Review have made a mistake. Don't spend time on an alternative until you've queried the rejection - mistakes happen - or you might find it is wasted as the real reason for rejection comes back...

Comment: I'll send it to Apple, but a workaround won't be too hard. I've been running into a lot of roadblocks for this project. At this point, I just want to see it get submitted.

Comment: It's mentioned in docs here (though it's only OS X docs, so maybe they decided this shouldn't be public in iOS?): http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Optimizing/Optimizing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a mistake… anyways - What about `CGRectIntersectsRect`?

Comment: Tried it. Came up with the error message: `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CGIntersectsRect", referenced from:
      -[*AppName*ViewController fix] in *AppName*ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7`

Comment: @RaysonK you have a typo there (and likely a compiler warning)

Comment: That's just what the error message says. I copied it straight from the error console. Also, `fix` is the name of the method that uses `NSIntersectsRect` (or `CGIntersectsRect`, now...)

Comment: @Rayson nonono - the typo's in your source. it's `CGRectIntersectsRect` not `CGIntersectsRect`.

Comment: O_O I....you....Good Lord almighty, that was it! Build went through after I changed it. Jeez laweez, thanks for that catch!

Comment: @RaysonK please next time specify that it was for iOS, where CGRects are used.

Answer (score 1):

According to docs for NSIntersectionRect

`If the two rectangles don’t overlap, the returned rectangle has its origin at (0.0, 0.0) and zero width and height (including situations where the intersection is a point or a line segment)`

So my suggestion is create a method like

```
- (BOOL)rect:(NSRect)rect1 intersectsRect:(NSRect)rect2 {
    NSRect testRect = NSIntersectionRect(rect1, rect2);
    return !NSEqualRects(testRect, NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is seriously annoying. What you said made sense, and I put in the code verbatim, but somehow Xcode doesn't recognize NSRect as a type. I tried using CGIntersectsRect, but that didn't help, either. Is this a common bug for Xcode 4.2?

Comment: NSRect is a Mac OS X type—on iOS, you want the CG* version.